# How to use register_nav_menus in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm creating a custom wordpress design with the help of an instruction book and got stuck with the menu creation.

I should input the following code in functions.php

```
register_nav_menus( array(
        'fomenu'   => __( 'Fomenu', 'smaragdkerteszet' ),
        'kismenu'  => __( 'Kismenu', 'smaragdkerteszet' ),
) );
```

After that I should be able to go to Appearance/menus in the admin panel and choose between the 2 menus in a drop-down list but this list does not appear.

What do I need to fix?

Comment: When you visit wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=locations, do you see your menus listed?

Comment: No. When I entered your url it changes to wp-admin/nav-menus.php?action=edit&menu=0, but I couldn't see that the menus are listed. I only entered the code I mentioned above just to register the menus, edit them in Wordpress and later make the menus appear on the page.

Comment: Your above code is working properly. May be there is some error in other part of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow this code:

```
function register_all_menu(){
    register_nav_menus(
      array('top_menu' => 'Top Menu')
      );
 }
```

And add "show_top_menu" in the place that you want to display nav menu.

```
Function show_top_menu(){
    $topMenu = array(
       'theme_location' => 'top_menu',
       'container' =>'false',
       'item_wraper' => '<ul id ="top_menu" class="%2$s">3$s</ul>'  
       );
wp_nav_menu($topMenu);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an `add_action` can help:

```
// Register your menus
function my_custom_menus() {
    $locations = array(
        'fomenu'   => __( 'Fomenu', 'smaragdkerteszet' ),
        'kismenu'  => __( 'Kismenu', 'smaragdkerteszet' ),
    );
    register_nav_menus( $locations );
 }

// Hook them into the theme-'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'my_custom_menus' );
```